# Coordinate matrices in standard basis

Tags: vector-spaces

If $A=1+2x+4x^3$ and $B=2+3x^2+x^3$ are vectors in Polynomial space, find out the coordinate matrices for $A$ and $B$ in standard basis and hence find out the angle between vectors A and B.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: If the standard basis is $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\},$ how can you write $A$ and $B?$

Comment: The standard basis is {1,x,x^2,x^3}

Comment: Yes. So, do you see how to write $A$ and $B$ as vector with respect to that basis?

Comment: Well I think, by taking their coefficients, we can write the vectors in standard basis, so for A, we have (1,0,2,4) and B=(2,0,3,1)

Comment: Yes on $B$; close-but-not-quite on $A$. Now, once you have these two vectors, do you know how to find the angle between them?

Comment: By using the cosine of the angle between the vectors, scalar product divided by the product of the magnitude of the vectors

Comment: There you go. You can write that up and post it as an answer.

Comment: But, you told me that the coordinate matrix for A is not quite correct, Why?

Comment: OK, take the vector you wrote for $A$, that is, $(1,0,2,4)$, and turn it back into a polynomial --- what do you get? Do you actually get $A$, or something somewhat different?

Comment: Thanks Gerry, Now I can see my mistake in here. I should have written (1,2,0,4) instead. It would be great if you could write the whole answer by yourself instead.

Answer (score 1):

As OP now understands, $A$ is represented by $u=(1,2,0,4)$ and $B$ by $v=(2,0,3,1)$. Write $\theta$ for the angle between; then $$\cos\theta={u\cdot v\over\|u\|\,\|v\|}={6\over\sqrt{21}\,\sqrt{14}}={\sqrt6\over7}$$ Now a calculator will get you a value for $\theta$, if needed.